# How to use an exported function in a script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, function, export

How can I use my export function in my html script tag. I have marked the function as export so that I can use it in my Jasmine UnitTests. However, I can no longer use my function in my html script tag and get the following error message:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: add is not defined`

Is there any way I can solve or work around this problem?

My `file.js`:

```
export function add(num1, num2) {
    const errorMessage = "Please enter a valid number";
    if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
        return errorMessage;
    }
    return num1 + num2
}
```

My `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Sample</title>
    <script type="module" src="file.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <input type="number" id="num1" placeholder="Erste Zahl">
    <input type="number" id="num2" placeholder="Zweite Zahl">
    <button onclick="addNumbers()">Addiere</button>
    <p id="additionResult"></p>
</div>

<script>

    function addNumbers() {
        const num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num1').value);
        const num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num2').value);
        const result = add(num1, num2)
        document.getElementById('additionResult').innerText = `Ergebnis der Addition: ${result}`;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Unittest:

```
import {add} from '../file.js'

describe('MyTest', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
    });

    describe("add Funktion", function () {
        it("sollte zwei Zahlen korrekt addieren", function () {
            expect(add(2, 3)).toEqual(5);
            expect(add(0, 0)).toEqual(0);
            expect(add(-1, 1)).toEqual(0);
        });

        it("sollte eine Fehlermeldung zurückgeben, wenn ungültige Eingaben gemacht werden", function () {
            expect(add("a", 2)).toEqual("Bitte geben Sie gültige Zahlen ein.");
            expect(add(1, "b")).toEqual("Bitte geben Sie gültige Zahlen ein.");
            expect(add("abc", "def")).toEqual("Bitte geben Sie gültige Zahlen ein.");
        });

        it("sollte eine Fehlermeldung zurückgeben, wenn eine Eingabe fehlt", function () {
            expect(add(2)).toEqual("Bitte geben Sie gültige Zahlen ein.");
            expect(add()).toEqual("Bitte geben Sie gültige Zahlen ein.");
        });
    });
});
```

If anyone has an answer I would be very pleased for a detailed response, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `type="module"` on the script that uses the `add` function and import the function from `file.js`.

```
<script type="module">
import { add } from './file.js';
function addNumbers() {
    // ...
}
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', addNumbers);
</script>
```

Comment: Does not work, i get following error: ```Uncaught ReferenceError: addNumbers is not defined```

Comment: @eXor420 Use `addEventListener` instead of inline event handlers: `document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', addNumbers);`